# MongoDB compare I.P. Addresses

Tags: mongodb

I have a csv of ~600k records of I.P.s and country codes (from https://db-ip.com) that I have imported in mongoDB, the structure is as follows:

```
{
    addr_type: "ipv4",
    ip_start: "176.74.160.0",
    ip_end: "176.74.179.207",
    country: "GB"
}
```

Normally in SQL, I would save the "ip_start" and "ip_end" columns as VARBINARY(16) and then I can run this query:

```
select * from `{$table_name}` where addr_type = ? and ip_start <= ? order by ip_start desc limit 1
```

In mongoDB there is no VARBINARY type, I tried to insert them as strings, but it didn't return to correct values:

```
var country bson.M
ip := "85.134.123.13"
Db := db.MgoDb{}
Db.Init()
c := Db.C("dbip")
if err := c.Find(bson.M{"addr_type": "ipv4", "ip_start": bson.M{"$lte": ip}}).Select(bson.M{"country":1, "_id":0}).Sort("ip_start").One(&country); err != nil { 
    log.Printf(err.Error())
}
Db.Close()
```

Any ideas how compare I.P. with MongoDB like in the SQL example from above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would treat the IP addresses as 32 bit integers (assuming IPv4). You can easily convert using [net.ParseIP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ParseIP). For example:

```
binary.BigEndian.Uint32(net.ParseIP("85.134.123.13").To4())
```

Once these are stored as integers then finding a particular IP is a simple numeric comparison in the query.

Otherwise, you could use `net.ParseIP` to generate the `[]byte` slices, store these as binary and compare like you did in SQL. The resulting bytes slices are always 16 bytes long so only the last 4 bytes are used if an IPv4 address was parsed.

Comment: Thank you for answer, will this also work with IPv6? Because I am storing both IPv4 and IPv6 in my database.

Comment: I made here an example with what you are saying, but it prints 0.
https://play.golang.org/p/KJSMJlUdV-

Comment: I updated my answer, hadn't actually ran the code I typed. See https://play.golang.org/p/O7SHmIuwCw